# How do I remove an imported folder from Notes.app?

Tags: big-sur, notes.app

I accidentally imported my entire filesystem as a folder in the Notes app on MacOS 11.3.1. Obviously, this is now causing Notes to be largely unresponsive, and frequently crash. I do not have the option to delete the folder from the Notes app.

[image]

How can I remove this folder? Is it possible to remove it without losing my actual Notes?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up using was saving all my actual notes to text files, then removing three files:

```
~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes/NoteStore.sqlite
~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes/NoteStore.sqlite-shm
~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes/NoteStore.sqlite-wal
```

This completely cleared my Notes history/status. Would love to hear a solution that would have preserved my Notes, though.

Comment: Did you try to access Notes from iCloud?  I wonder if it would have loaded quicker or enough for you to delete the items.

Comment: @CraigHindall I did not have Notes synced with iCloud.